# Can not upgrade 18.04 to 19.04 beause libre is not upgraded

Tags: apt, upgrade, libreoffice

I am in a deadlock currently
Trying to upgrade to 19.04,but can not because of packages were kept back

```
kireto@kireto-laptop3:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-writer linux-generic linux-headers-generic
  linux-image-generic python3-uno
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
kireto@kireto-laptop3:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Is there some thing I could do?

Comment: fyi:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is tested & expected to upgrade from one release to the next, or skip to the next LTS, so the tested & supported upgrade paths from 18.04 LTS are (1) to 18.10, or (2) wait till Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS is released and release-upgrade to that.  18.04 straight to 19.04 is untested & unsupported

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade those packages you can just run `sudo apt full-upgrade`.